# How do I correlate a Linq query extension method to its signature in the documentation?

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

Take this code from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The following code example demonstrates how to use
>   Where(IEnumerable, Func) to filter
>   a sequence.

```
List<string> fruits =
    new List<string> { "apple", "passionfruit", "banana", "mango", 
                    "orange", "blueberry", "grape", "strawberry" };

IEnumerable<string> query = fruits.Where(fruit => fruit.Length < 6);

foreach (string fruit in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fruit);
}
/*
 This code produces the following output:

 apple
 mango
 grape
*/
```

When I look at the signature,

`Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)`

Which part of `(fruit => fruit.length < 6)` is `IEnumerable<TSource>`?  And does `Func<TSource, Boolean>` include the entire lambda or just what comes after the `=>`?  I am guessing that behind the scenes Where's `<TSource>` is replaced by the compiler with the correct type for the Generic, but I don't know how to read the rest.

EDIT:  Would it be easier to understand if this were a delegate instead of a lambda, as far as seeing what points to what in the documentation?

Comment: Since it's an extension method, the first parameter is the object you're "dotting" from. In that case, the `fruits` part is the first param. In other words, `foo.Where(bar)` is being translated to `Where(foo, bar)`.

Comment: You need to learn how extension methods work.  The internets can help!

Comment: @Will SO is on the Internets.

Comment: @johnny Except SO is a Q&A site, you need a tutorial site or [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I used that.  That's why I'm here.  It did not fill in the gaps for me.  I read a while before I posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the method signature you see it defined as

```
public static Enumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, bool> predicate
    )
}
```

the `this` makes it a extension method. so doing

```
fruits.Where(fruit => fruit.Length < 6);
```

is the exact same thing as doing

```
Enumerable.Where(fruits, fruit => fruit.Length < 6);
```

So to answer your question the `IEnumerable<T>` is to the left of the `.`

Comment: What about the Func part?  Is fruit the TSource there?

Comment: `TSource` is infered from the `IEnumerable<T>`, because you passed in a `IEnumerable<string>` then `TSource` is a `string`. Written as a normal function the second parameter is `bool myFunction(string fruit) { return fruit.Length < 6; }` doing `fruits.Where(myFunction);` is legal code.

Comment: The part to the left of the `=>` in a lambada is just the declaration of the parameters for the anonymous delegate you are creating.